# Rails AJAX form submission succeeds, but nothing happens on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm trying to modify a form in a Rails to-do list app to use AJAX instead of HTML. I've gotten the form to submit on the back end, but on the front end, the page does nothing. Upon submission, I would like to display the list via AJAX.

Here is my form – `app/views/lists/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@list, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @list.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this list from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @list.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task| %>
    <li>
      <%= task.label :name %>       <%= task.text_field :name %>
      <%= task.label :due %>        <%= task.datetime_select :due, ampm: true %>
      <%= task.label :completed %>  <%= task.check_box :completed %>
    </li>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is the CoffeeScript for the page on which the form is being rendered – `app/assets/javascripts/lists.coffee`:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("new_list").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("new_list").append xhr.responseText
  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("new_list").append "<p>Error!</p>"
```

Submitting the form succeeds on the back end…

```
Started POST "/lists" for ::1 at 2016-06-12 14:28:43 -0400
Processing by ListsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "list"=>{"name"=>"Groceries", "tasks_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Apples", "due(1i)"=>"2016", "due(2i)"=>"6", "due(3i)"=>"12", "due(4i)"=>"18", "due(5i)"=>"28", "completed"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"Bananas", "due(1i)"=>"2016", "due(2i)"=>"6", "due(3i)"=>"12", "due(4i)"=>"18", "due(5i)"=>"28", "completed"=>"0"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"Oranges", "due(1i)"=>"2016", "due(2i)"=>"6", "due(3i)"=>"12", "due(4i)"=>"18", "due(5i)"=>"28", "completed"=>"0"}}}, "commit"=>"Create List"}
  User Load (4.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "lists" ("name", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Groceries"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-06-12 18:28:43.050750"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-12 18:28:43.050750"]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("name", "completed", "due", "list_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Apples"], ["completed", "f"], ["due", "2016-06-12 18:28:00.000000"], ["list_id", 22], ["created_at", "2016-06-12 18:28:43.055160"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-12 18:28:43.055160"]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("name", "completed", "due", "list_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Bananas"], ["completed", "f"], ["due", "2016-06-12 18:28:00.000000"], ["list_id", 22], ["created_at", "2016-06-12 18:28:43.058809"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-12 18:28:43.058809"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("name", "completed", "due", "list_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Oranges"], ["completed", "f"], ["due", "2016-06-12 18:28:00.000000"], ["list_id", 22], ["created_at", "2016-06-12 18:28:43.061804"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-12 18:28:43.061804"]]
   (4.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/lists/22
Completed 302 Found in 42ms (ActiveRecord: 12.1ms)

Started GET "/lists/22" for ::1 at 2016-06-12 14:28:43 -0400
Processing by ListsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"22"}
  List Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 22]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Task Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."list_id" = $1  [["list_id", 22]]
  Rendered lists/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)
  Rendered application/_nav.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 418ms (Views: 411.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

…but nothing happens on the page. How can I load the newly created list into the page via AJAX?

Apologies for the wall of code, and thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:** I was able to get the newly created list to render on the page, but it appears *below* the existing page contents. I changed the `format.json` for saved lists:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @list.save
    format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @list.to_json }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

Comment: Added details for the `show` action that executes after the redirect; this does not actually show on the page.

Comment: I was able to render the newly created list on the page, but it appears _below_ the existing page contents. Details above.

Answer (score 0):

`$("new_list")` is looking for a tag `<new_list>` which most likely doesn't exist.

Not clear from code shown what it is referencing so if it's an id prefix selector  with `#` and if it's a class prefix with `.`

Also not clear how form submit works

Comment: Good call. I've changed `$("new_list")` to `$("#new_list")` to match the selector for the form, but it's still not working. What specifically about the form submission mechanism are you finding unclear? Happy to add more details as needed. Thanks!

Comment: Does form submit by ajax? or does page reload on submit? Also make sure to use `document.ready`

Comment: The form submits via AJAX; the page does not reload. I am using `document.ready`, as is visible in the code snippet above.